# Retrieving Values from sorted list based on the index of the selected item in combobox

Tags: vb.net, sortedlist

Ok, so here is what I am trying to do:

I have names and ID's in a sorted list where the name is the key and the ID is the value. I load a combobox with the keys (names) as such:

```
For Each key In students.Keys
  cmbStudent.Items.Add(key)
Next
```

In an adjacent textbox, I would like to fill the value of the selected key. I create the sorted list on the Load event.  So in my mind, I would have to take the `selectedItem.tostring()` and search the sorted list for the value, but I can't figure it out. I've never used a `sortedList` before and it certainly seems like the right thing to use for this, but who knows! lol

In any event, I would really appreciate guidance as opposed to a solution otherwise I won't learn anything! Thank you!

Comment: It's not wrong. You can use a BindingSource to bind the SortedList to the Combobox, e.g., `cmbStudent.DisplayMember = "Key" cmbStudent.ValueMember = "Value" cmbStudent.DataSource = new BindingSource(yourSortedList, nothing)`. After that, in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler of your ComboBox, `someTextBox.Text = cmbStudent.SelectedValue?.ToString()`. Or add a DataBinding to the TextBox.Text property. You could also use the generic SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtID.text = students(cmbStudent.selectedItem.ToString())
```

Another (less efficient) way would be to loop through all the items in the sorted list, check if it matches the key you want, and if so, then add the value to the text box.

i.e.

```
  For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In students

        if item.Key = cmbStudent.selectedItem.ToString() then txtID.text = item.Value

   Next
```

Regarding guidance:

You're simply extracting the value (ID in this case) from the sortedlist based on the key you pass to it (the string of the key that is being taken from the selected key in the combo-box)

Have a look at this:

https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/visual-basic/vb-sorted-list

Comment: Well...I can't believe it was just that simple (actually I can, but a little disappointed that I couldn't figure that out myself).  Thank you, it works perfectly.  Also thank you for the link.  I definitely learned new things today.

Comment: @MoJoMan don't feel bad, it happens to all of us here and there, even veteran coders, especially when learning a new language. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I filled a `SortedList` in `Form.Load` and set the display and value members of the combo. Set the `DataSource` to the sorted list calling `.ToList` since `SortedList` does not implement `IList`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lst As New SortedList(Of String, Integer)
    lst.Add("Mathew", 1)
    lst.Add("Mark", 2)
    lst.Add("Luke", 3)
    lst.Add("John", 4)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = lst.ToList
End Sub
```

Then, when the selection changes, retrieve the `SelectedValue`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim value = ComboBox1.SelectedValue 'This returns an object but can be cast to underlying type
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is the path I thought I was on. I was missing the displaymember/valuemember/datasource piece.  Now it makes sense!